# Calculate cosine similarity between a pandas Dataframe column and a list containing string values

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing

I am currently doing this:

```
def word2vec(word):
    from collections import Counter
    from math import sqrt

    # count the characters in word
    cw = Counter(word)
    # precomputes a set of the different characters
    sw = set(cw)
    # precomputes the "length" of the word vector
    lw = sqrt(sum(c*c for c in cw.values()))

    # return a tuple
    return cw, sw, lw

def cosdis(v1, v2):
    # which characters are common to the two words?
    common = v1[1].intersection(v2[1])
    # by definition of cosine distance we have
    return sum(v1[0][ch]*v2[0][ch] for ch in common)/v1[2]/v2[2]

x= pd.DataFrame('id':['ABD','VWR', 'KPE', 'FFT'], Score:[30,23,25,21])
l1 = ['A', 'AB', 'KA', 'FF']
cosd={}

for i in l1:
    for index, j in x.iterrows():            
        cosd[i] = [j['id'], cosdis(word2vec(i), word2vec(j['id']))]
```

But i would like a faster and more optimized way of doing it. I have tried using pandas.apply function.

Comment: try checking `np.dot` it would be much more faster. make sure to normalize the embeddings first

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cosine_similarity](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html) function from [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/) which is a vectorized version of cosine similarity computation. So it will be much faster than computing in a for loop.

Assuming that you have already `word2vec` values (with length 100) of the arrays `l1 = ['ABD','VWR', 'KPE', 'FFT']` and  `l2 = ['A', 'AB', 'KA', 'FF']`, so you will have two `[4 x 100]` sized matrix. I will randomly generate them by using [numpy](https://numpy.org/) library since I have not `word2vec` implementation:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

l1 = np.random.rand(4, 100)
l2 = np.random.rand(4, 100)

print(cosine_similarity(l1, l2))
```

The output will be resulted as follows:

```
array([[0.75745762, 0.72183435, 0.74484246, 0.75241425],
       [0.68973308, 0.66498995, 0.63636494, 0.72047839],
       [0.79790214, 0.78010733, 0.77533   , 0.79282891],
       [0.76284434, 0.78694741, 0.76122869, 0.73728549]])
```

In order to check the similarity between the word2vec at index `0` in `l1` which is `'ABD'` and the word2vec at index `1` in `l2` which is `'AB'`, you need to check the `cosine_similarity(l1, l2)[0][1]` which is `0.72183435`

In addition, if we check that the cosine similarity of `l1` with itself, it will be symmetric and diagonal matrix will be full of ones.

```
print(cosine_similarity(l1, l1))
array([[1.        , 0.71591033, 0.83635512, 0.801628  ],
       [0.71591033, 1.        , 0.75567587, 0.73614333],
       [0.83635512, 0.75567587, 1.        , 0.82238456],
       [0.801628  , 0.73614333, 0.82238456, 1.        ]])
```

**Edit:**

Since you are asking for the cosine similarity between a dataframe and a list, you need to convert them to numpy arrays before the passing them through `cosine_similarity` function. Following should work fine:

```
word2vec_l1, word2vec_l2 = [], []

for i in x['id'].values:
  word2vec_l1.append(word2vec(i))

# This l2 is the l1 in your question which is ['A', 'AB', 'KA', 'FF']
for i in l2:
  word2vec_l2.append(word2vec(i))

word2vec_l1 = np.array(word2vec_l1)
word2vec_l2 = np.array(word2vec_l2)
```

Then you can compute the cosine similarity by:

```
cos_sim = cosine_similarity(word2vec_l1, word2vec_l2)
```